# App.Config in a class library for data access from WPF and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, data-access-layer, class-library

I'm trying to use SQL for the first time to store data in one of my projects, I'm using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Et2khGnrIqc&list=PLLWMQd6PeGY3b89Ni7xsNZddi9wD5Esv2) tutorial as it makes the most sense to me, and to be honest I like the guys videos, and hate clicking on hundreds of bad videos before finding one I can learn from.

Anyway I'm making an app where I need to access and save to a SQL database I have made in MSSMS, I have a class library for logic, a data class library for data access, and a WPF interface (I also plan to add an ASP interface with less edit features, but adding Web API, its all for learning)

In the video to connect dapper the guy sets up a helper to get the connection string, but that is looking up an App.Config through configuration manager (which he says is baked in and you just need to add a reference, but it seems now is a NuGet package).

But I have no `App.config` anywhere, and I've never used that so I don't know if I'm supposed to add it, will it do anything, where would I add it? Or do I do something completely different nowadays using .NET Core not .NET Framework.

Sorry long post and maybe not as clear as it should be but I'm struggling here at the first hurdle and Google seems to be useless on this one.

As a side note I'm also planning to save key value pairs from my objects (as `Dictionary<string, string>`), *am I best just having a new table just for those and store the I'd of the object it was associated with, the key, and the value in their own columns?*

Comment: Your "TOP LAYER" will have the ConnectionStrings.

So that is either a Console.exe application or a web(webapi/webmvc), etc. .netcore has "appsettings.json" now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just going to my UI Add > New Item > Application Configuration File, called App.config and using this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear/>
        <add name="Thenameasusedinmyapp" connectionString="Server =.; Database = NameofDatabase; Trusted_Connection = True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic dotnet core command line exe

Note, this is a loose mini implementation of what is in this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures

https://github.com/granadacoder/dotnet-core-on-linux-one/tree/master/src/ConsoleOne

typical appsettings.json contents

https://github.com/granadacoder/dotnet-core-on-linux-one/blob/master/src/ConsoleOne/appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Data Source=someServer\someInstance,1433;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=Password1#;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

this top layer has and defines these values.  in my sample "ConsoleOne" is the top layer.

I also have a BAL and DAL layers.

https://github.com/granadacoder/dotnet-core-on-linux-one/tree/master/src/Bal

https://github.com/granadacoder/dotnet-core-on-linux-one/tree/master/src/Dal

my example uses Dapper, and it fishes the connection string

https://github.com/granadacoder/dotnet-core-on-linux-one/blob/master/src/Dal/EmployeeDataLayer.cs

```
public class EmployeeDataLayer : IEmployeeDataLayer
{
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration config;

    public EmployeeDataLayer(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            string connectionString = this.config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
            return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
    }

    public async Task<Employee> GetByID(int id)
    {
        using (IDbConnection conn = this.Connection)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth FROM Employee WHERE ID = @ID";
            sql = "SELECT TOP 1 id as ID, 'FName' + name as FirstName, 'LName' + name as LastName, crdate as DateOfBirth FROM sysobjects order by id";
            conn.Open();
            var result = await conn.QueryAsync<Employee>(sql, new { ID = id });
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<Employee>> GetByDateOfBirth(DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        using (IDbConnection conn = this.Connection)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth FROM Employee WHERE DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth";
            sql = "SELECT TOP 3 id as ID, 'FName' + name as FirstName, 'LName' + name as LastName, crdate as DateOfBirth FROM sysobjects order by id";

            conn.Open();
            var result = await conn.QueryAsync<Employee>(sql, new { DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth });
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

(Note, my DAL code above is not hitting real backend tables, it is a simple demo I did)

But back to the configuration:

I accomplish this by "injecting" the Configuration object into the class (see the constructor)

With dotnet-core, you typically use the built in IoC/DI

You can see that here:

https://github.com/granadacoder/dotnet-core-on-linux-one/blob/master/src/ConsoleOne/Program.cs

```
    private static IServiceProvider BuildDi(IConfiguration config)
    {
        string connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");


        return new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IEmployeeManager, EmployeeManager>()
            .AddTransient<IEmployeeDataLayer, EmployeeDataLayer>()

            .AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                // configure Logging with NLog
                loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
                loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                loggingBuilder.AddNLog(config);
            })

            .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config)
            .BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

Comment: I dont have a console application for this, should I add this json to my WPF app and then clone it when I have my ASP.NET project set up in the solution?

Comment: Right.  The top layer can be a WPF App.  Then that would reference the BAL and DAL.

Comment: Actually thats a whole lot of information I think I need some time to understand all that and I'll get back on here with how its worked out for me.

Comment: Here is another link:    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures